# loops written in Python take a lot of time

Tags: python, numpy

I was making this blue colored filter using openCV in python and it works but the video output is lagging.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()  
    for i in range(frame.shape[0]):
        for j in range(frame.shape[1]):
            frame[i][j] = [255,frame[i][j][1],frame[i][j][2]]

    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()  
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I believe that loop is just a long way to write `frame[:, :, 0] = 255`.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if you have to write a `for` loop when working with numpy arrays, you're doing it wrong. Numpy supports extremely rich [array broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html), which is orders of magnitude more efficient than "equivalent" Python loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize vectorized operations in NumPy to avoid the explicit loops:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    
    frame[:, :, 0] = 255  # Set blue channel to 255 (full blue)
    
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```